# Hook function call for every used vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to raise a counter in my vue component every time I use the component. The goal should be a name with a suffix of `counter` i.e. `name="tool-2"`

Here is my .vue file:
ToolGuiComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{elementName}}</label>
    <input type="text" :name="getCount()"></input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'tool-gui-component',
        props : ['elementName'],
        data : function(){
            return {
                counter : 0
            }
        },
        created : function(){
            this.counter++
        },
        methods : {
            getCount : function() {
                return "tool-"+this.counter
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I tried it with the `created` hook but it only raises the counter by 1. Using `ready` did not helped either. Sadly I could not find any API listing of component hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `counter` is scoped variable and it is created every time you create a component, so you will only increment it once per every instance of your component.

You can create "per module" variable and increment it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{elementName}}</label>
    <input type="text" :name="getCount()"></input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    var counter = 0;

    export default {
        name: 'tool-gui-component',
        props : ['elementName'],
        created : function(){
            counter++
        },
        methods : {
            getCount : function() {
                return "tool-" + counter
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: 
Also in your case, you don't even need `getCount` function, you can do it as simply as that:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{elementName}}</label>
    <input type="text" :name="name"></input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    var counter = 0;

    export default {
        name: 'tool-gui-component',
        props : ['elementName'],
        data() {
          name: 'tool-' + (counter++)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Reason being is that `.data()` function will be called every time the new instance of the component is created, so it is exactly what you need.